# Dictionary Comprehension: How do we build a dictionary with integers as keys and tuples as values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of data and they are formated like this: (have more lines below are just part of them)

```
2   377222  TOYOTA MOTOR CORPORATION    TOYOTA  PASEO   1994    Y   19941226    N   0   0   PARKING BRAKE:CONVENTIONAL  SAN JOSE        CA  JT2EL45U5R0 19950103    19950103        1   PARKED ON FLAT SURFACE EMERGENCY BRAKING ENGAGED VEHICLE ROLLED REARWARD.  TT   EVOQ                                                                                                    V           
1   958164  TOYOTA MOTOR CORPORATION    TOYOTA  LAND CRUISER    1994        19941223    N   0   0   SERVICE BRAKES, HYDRAULIC:ANTILOCK  ARNOLD          CA  JT3DJ81W8R0 19950103    19950103            ABS SYSTEM FAILURE, AT 20MPH.  TT   EVOQ                                                                                                    V
46  958153  DAIMLERCHRYSLER CORPORATION DODGE   CARAVAN 1987        19940901    N   0   0   EQUIPMENT:MECHANICAL:CARRIER/RACK   CORBETT         OR  2B4FK4130HR 19950103    19950103        1   CABLE ATTACHMENT THAT SECURES THE SPARE TIRE BROKE WHILE DRIVING.  TT   EVOQ                                                                                                    V   
98  958178  GENERAL MOTORS CORP.    GMC SAFARI  1994        19941223    N   0   0   SERVICE BRAKES, HYDRAULIC:FOUNDATION COMPONENTS MILAN           MI  1GDDM19W4RB 19950103    19950103        1   BRAKES FAILED DUE TO BATTERY MALFUNCTIONING WHEN TOO MUCH POWER WAS DRAWN FROM BATTERY FOR RADIO.   TT  EVOQ                                                                                                    V
```

What is the best way to create a dictionary using index(1) the integer as keys and a tuple of any other 2 elements in the sentence as values? The desired output should be like this:

```
function(filename)[2]
('TOTOTA MOTOR CORPORATION','19941226','SAN JOSE','CA')
```

Here is what I have right now and I was trying to put them all into a dictionary first but it wont iterate through he entire list instead it just returns the elements of a single line. What went wrong with my code? or How do I at least accomplish the first step - putting them all in a dictionary?

```
def function(filename):
    with open filename as FileObject:
        A=[]
        for lines in FileObject:
            B=[line.split("\t")[0]]
            A+=B
            C=[line.split("\t")[2]]
            A=A+B+C
            D=[line.split("\t")[12]]
            A=A+B+C+D
            E={A:(B,C,D)for A in A}
    return E
print function(filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new dictionary (not adding to it) each time through the loop (`E={A:(B,C,D)for A in A}`).  Declare your dictionary BEFORE you enter the loop, and add your entry each time THROUGH the loop.

```
def create_database(f)
    """ Returns a populated dictionary.  Iterates over the input 'f'. """
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        # add stuff to data
        key, datum = parse_line(line)
        data[key] = datum
    return data
```

Comment: thanks. so that way the parse_line function will create the keys and values for the dictionary in the end?

Comment: Yeah.  I originally included a `parse_line` function, but seeing as this is probably a homework problem (right?), I deleted it.  You can either use the CSV module as @JonClements suggested, or you can split over tabs like you do in your original code. Either way, you should only need to use `.split` *once*-- store it in a variable, and slice into the variable for the indexes you want to access.

Comment: Sure thing.  Incidentally, the cool thing about defining `create_database` and `parse_line` this way, is that it can be written *very* elegantly using a list comprehension inside of a dict comprehension; you should give that a shot after you're done writing `parse_line`,

Comment: I have a question....@kreativitea     What does key,datum=parse_line(line) mean? what is datum?

Comment: @BRAYBRAY It's an arbitrary variable that stores the result from parse_line.  Functions can return more than one result, and in this case, we want `parse_line()` to return a key (the integer `2` in your example) and a datum (a tuple with the data you're looking for, in your example case, `('TOTOTA MOTOR CORPORATION','19941226','SAN JOSE','CA')`.  That way, when you ask the dictionary for the item corresponding to the key `2`, it returns the full tuple.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `csv` module (which can be used to process tab delimited files) and possibly `operator.itemgetter` as a convenience function.

```
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    tabin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    # change itemgetter to include the relevant column indices
    your_dict = {int(row[0]): itemgetter(2, 12)(row) for row in tabin}

print your_dict[2]
```

Comment: @BRAYBRAY It wasn't aimed at you specifically - was just an open question to who did downvote it asking if they wouldn't mind explaining why

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I have a question though, for this method....what if I want return a formated result? For example I want to define another function to define the format and then how I can make it work using this function?@Jon Clements